# Lua For/do loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua

I am trying to create a mod for a game server that i am playing, the idea is to give flag permissions to people based on being a mod or admin. The flags can be assigned by the server owner in a config file.

What i am trying to create, is a for loop that reads a section of the config file and passes the index and value to a function that then sends the information to the server.

---

```
function PLUGIN:cmdgiveflags ( netuser , cmd, args )
if (netuser:CanAdmin()) then
    local a, targetuser = rust.FindNetUsersByName( args[1] )
    if (not a) then
        if (targetuser == 0) then
            rust.Notice( netuser , "No Players by that name!" )
        else
            rust.Notice( netuser , "Multiple Players by the name!" )
        end
        return
    end
    if ( args[2] == "admin" ) then
        **for key,value in pairs(self.Config.admin) do self.addflag(targetuser,key,value) end**
    elseif ( args[2] == "mod") then
        **for key,value in pairs(self.Config.mod) do self.addflag(targetuser,key,value) end**
    else
        rust.Notice( netuser , "Invalid Option, must be mod or admin" )
    end
else    
    rust.Notice( netuser , "Only and Admin can use this command" )
end
end

function PLUGIN:addflag (targetuser, key, value)
print ("targetuser is "..targetuser)
**print ("key is "..key)**
**print ("value is "..value)**
if (value == true) then
    if (key == "cangod" ) or (key == "canban") or (key == "cankick") or (key == "all") then
        rust.RunServerCommand( "oxmin.giveflag " .. targetuser .. " " .. key )
        print (targetuser .. " has been given the flag: " .. key )
    else 
        rust.RunServerCommand( "flags.addflag " .. targetuser .. " " .. key )
        print (targetuser .. " has been given the flag: " .. key )
    end
end
end
```

The problem that i am having is when the variables key and value are sent to the addflags functions, key shows up as true and value is nil. but if i just do print(key,value) in the for loop they come out as expected. I only just started coding in Lua so I'm not too sure what the rules all are just yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Oh and sorry if the code isnt formatted correctly on the site, not sure how to get it to paste with the correct formatting.

Comment: "Lua (/ˈluːə/ loo-ə, from Portuguese: lua [ˈlu.(w)ɐ] meaning moon; explicitly not "LUA"[1])" - **forget those all caps.**

Comment: I'm sorry. Do you have any comments besides the incorrect capitalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `self:addflag` instead of `self.addflag`.

The definition

```
function PLUGIN:addflag (targetuser, key, value)
```

is sugar for

```
function PLUGIN.addflag (self, targetuser, key, value)
```

The call

```
self:addflag(targetuser,key,value)
```

is sugar for

```
self.addflag(self,targetuser,key,value)
```

So you have to make a call that is consistent with the definition of the function.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Could you explain the difference between self: and self.?